# Is there an wrapper object for SEL?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, selector

I want to add selectors to an NSMutableArray. But since they're opaque types and no objects, that wouldn't work, right? Is there an wrapper object I can use? Or do I have to create my own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the NSString name of the selector in the array and use

```
SEL mySelector = NSSelectorFromString([selectorArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

to generate the selector from the stored string.

Additionally, you can package up the selector as an NSInvocation using something like

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[self methodSignatureForSelector:mySelector]];

[invocation setTarget:self];
[invocation setSelector:mySelector];
[invocation setArgument:&arg atIndex:2];
[invocation retainArguments];
```

This NSInvocation object can then be stored in the array and invoked later.

Answer (score 9):

You can wrap it in an `NSValue` instance as follows:

```
SEL mySelector = @selector(performSomething:);
NSValue *value = [NSValue value:&mySelector withObjCType:@encode(SEL)];
```

and then add value to your `NSMutableArray` instance.

Answer (score 2):

NSValue valueWithPointer / pointerValue works equally well.

you just need to know that you can't serialise the array (ie write it to a file) if you want to do that, use the NSStringFromSelector approach.

these are all valid ways of putting a selector into an NSValue object:

```
    id selWrapper1 = [NSValue valueWithPointer:_cmd];
    id selWrapper2 = [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(viewDidLoad)];
    id selWrapper3 = [NSValue valueWithPointer:@selector(setObject:forKey:)];
    NSString *myProperty = @"frame";
    NSString *propertySetter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@%@:",
                                [[myProperty substringToIndex:1]uppercaseString],
                                [myProperty substringFromIndex:1]];

    id selWrapper4 = [NSValue valueWithPointer:NSSelectorFromString(propertySetter)];

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      selWrapper1,
                      selWrapper2,
                      selWrapper3,
                      selWrapper4, nil];

    SEL theCmd1 = [[array objectAtIndex:0] pointerValue];
    SEL theCmd2 = [[array objectAtIndex:1] pointerValue];
    SEL theCmd3 = [[array objectAtIndex:2] pointerValue];
    SEL theCmd4 = [[array objectAtIndex:3] pointerValue];
```